# MPAndroidChart and DataBinding

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart, android-databinding, butterknife

I have a fragment where I have MPAndroidChart and textViews. I understand that MPAndroidChart doesn't support Data Binding as indicated in here:
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/1382

Right now I am using ButterKnife to find my views, but want to migrate to Data Binding. I was wondering since that MPAndroidChart doesn't support Data Binding, is it possible to use both Data Binding and Butterknife in the same fragment ?

Butterknife for MPAndroidChart and DataBinding for my textviews.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible,

Butterknife and Databinding are two different things.

But why you want butterknife. See below

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
    android:id="@+id/pieChart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

You can access this field like this

```
ActivityMainBinding binding;
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
binding.pieChart.setVisibility(Visibility.INVISIBLE)
```

So no need of butterknife when you use data binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PieChart with data binding by following code
1. Bind your layout with fragmnet

```
setPieChart(fragmentDashboardBinding.piechart);
```

Declare Pie chart variable global

```
private PieChart piechart;   
    public void setPieChart(PieChart Pie_chart) {
            this.piechart = Pie_chart;
        }
```

And Set your data on PieChart form Update Method

```
@Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object arg) {

        DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel = (DashboardViewModel) observable;
        drivingScore = dashboardViewModel.getDrivingScore();
        LoadPieChart(drivingScore);
    }

private void LoadPieChart(DrivingScore drivingScore) {
//Do any thing with your piechart
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use MPAndroidChart with databinding.

Create a custom binding adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:setPieData")
fun setPieData(view: PieChart, data: List<SomeModel>?) {
val entries = mutableListOf<PieEntry>()

data.forEach { sweet ->
    // Fill the entires list
}
// Set the entries, decorate the pie  
}
```

Then in the xml:

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
            android:id="@+id/consumed_data_sweets_rating_chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/chart_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/material_component_cards_top_and_bottom_padding"
            android:setPieData="@{viewmodel.pieData}"
```

Where `viewmodel.pieData` is `LiveData<List<SomeModel>> models` in passed in ViewModel class.

So basically you have to reate custom data binding adapters for any properties of Charts you want to set.

[Link to my project,](https://github.com/deividasstr/sweets-counter) look for ChartBindingAdapters class to see my custom adapters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

> layout -tag must in xml file.

```
<layout >
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/lineChart"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ok"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:background="#0058b6" />


    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

In Activity,

```
ActivityMainBinding binding; // Declaration

binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

binding.lineChart.setVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE);
binding.button1.setVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE);

binding.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
    }
});
```